# Change color of label in Labeled

Tags: labeling, charts

I have a stacked bar chart and one of the bars in the chart shows the value. I am using Labeled to put the value where I need it, but I can't seem to figure out how to change the color of the text. I have tried using Style wrapped around the text, using LabelStyle->White within Labeled, and using LabelStyle with Directive, but nothing seems to affect the color of my text, which is hard to see on the blue bar. Here's my code:

```
myPercentPrecision[x_] := 
 SetPrecision[Interpreter["PercentFraction"][x], 4]
BarChart[{{Labeled[myPercentPrecision[.5833], 
    myPercentPrecision[.5833], Center, Bold, 18], 
   myPercentPrecision[1 - .5833]}, {Labeled[myPercentPrecision[.7519],
     myPercentPrecision[.7519], Center, Bold, 18], 
   myPercentPrecision[1 - .7519]}}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 ChartStyle -> {EdgeForm[], {LLCCBlue, LightGray}}, BarSpacing -> 1.5,
  ChartLabels -> {Placed[{Style["RDG-098\n", Bold, 22], 
     Style["RDG-099\n", Bold, 22]}, Above], None}, 
 ChartLegends -> 
  Placed[{Style["Successful", 18], Style["Unsuccessful", 18]}, Right]]
```

And the resulting output:
[image: stacked bar chart]

The bar chart is inside a Manipulate function, but I've also tried building it outside of Manipulate, and I'm having the same issue with the label color.

Comment: The code does not work on my machine. Could you provide a minimal and complete example? (myPercentPrecision etc. are undefined, try providing example data)

Comment: Just add the color you want the label to be after you specify the weight and size, `BarChart[{
  {Labeled[0.5, "White", Center, Bold, 18, White], 0.5},
  {Labeled[0.25, "Green", Center, Bold, 18, Green], 0.25}}, 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
 ChartStyle -> {EdgeForm[], {Red, LightGray}}, BarSpacing -> 1.5]` If this doesn't work, you might need to specify what version of MMA you have or post more complete code.

Comment: Updated post to provide a minimum working example.

Comment: @N.J.Evans I tried that and it didn't work. I'm using version 12 prerelease, although I tested in version 11.3 and had the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
myPercentPrecision[x_] := 
 SetPrecision[Interpreter["PercentFraction"][x], 4]
BarChart[
 {
  {Labeled[myPercentPrecision[.5833], myPercentPrecision[.5833], 
    Center, Bold, 18, White], 
   myPercentPrecision[1 - .5833]}, {Labeled[myPercentPrecision[.7519],
     myPercentPrecision[.7519], Center, Bold, 18, White], 
   myPercentPrecision[1 - .7519]}
  }
 , ChartLayout -> "Stacked"
 , ChartStyle -> {EdgeForm[], {Red, LightGray}}
 , BarSpacing -> 1.5
 , ChartLabels -> {Placed[{Style["RDG-098\n", Bold, 22], 
     Style["RDG-099\n", Bold, 22]}, Above], None}
 , ChartLegends -> 
  Placed[{Style["Successful", 18], Style["Unsuccessful", 18]}, Right]
 ]
```

Using your code, and replacing `LLCCBlue` with `Red` and adding `White` as the last argument to `Labeled`, I produce the following image:

[image]

Note: I am using v. 11.2 if your results are different, there may be a bug.

Comment: That's one of the things I've tried. Just tried it again, even in a fresh notebook, and no luck. I'll contact their support and see if it's a bug with 12.

Answer (score 0):

```
myPercentPrecision[x_] := SetPrecision[Interpreter["PercentFraction"][x], 4] BarChart[{{Labeled[myPercentPrecision[.5833], myPercentPrecision[.5833], Center, Bold, 18, Yellow], myPercentPrecision[1 - .5833]}, {Labeled[myPercentPrecision[.7519], myPercentPrecision[.7519], Center, Bold, 18, Green], myPercentPrecision[1 - .7519]}}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ChartStyle -> {EdgeForm[], {Red, LightGray}}, BarSpacing -> 1.5, ChartLabels -> {Placed[{Style["RDG-098\n", Bold, 22, Yellow], Style["RDG-099\n", Bold, 22, Red]}, Above], None}, ChartLegends -> Placed[{Style["Successful", 18, Green], 
Style["Unsuccessful", 18, Blue]}, Right]]
```

I am using M11.1, and it is just working fine. Which text exactly that could not change?

[image]